# R parse to cell values separate columns

Tags: r, parsing

This is a revised question structure.

Using R code, I want to expand a JSON file to a show all columns and rows, so that I can save as a csv file.

---

I have been attempting to expand the fields level to key, title, type and answer cols and rows.

```
json_data = {
    "name": "circle",
    “ID = [“1”, “2”, “3”],
    "questions": [
        {
            "local": "Q1",
            "fields": [
                {"key": ["abcde", "abcd"], "title": ["How many cats are meowing?", "How many cats are sleeping?"], "type": ["text", "text"], "answer": ["2", "5"]},
                {"key": "fghij", "title": "Number of dogs barking?", "type": "text", "answer": "2"},
                {"key": ["qwerty", "thnmjy"], "title": ["Number of cows in the field?", "How many sheep have lambs?"], "type": ["text", "text"], "answer": ["0", "7"]},
                {"key": "poiuy", "title": "Number of birds flying?", "type": "text", "answer": "0"},
                {"key": "lkjhg", "title": "How many frogs in the pond?", "type": "text", "answer": "3"},
                {"key": "mnbvc", "title": "How many fish swimming?", "type": "text", "answer": "4"}
            ],
            "category": "a",
            "index": "b"
       }
}
```

I attempted opening the JSON file using the following R script.

```
# Dummy data for df_1
df_1 <- data.frame(
  name = "circle",
  question = "local",
  ID = c(1, 2, 3),
  key = c(
    "c(abcde, abcd), c(How many cats are meowing?, How many cats are sleeping?) c(text, text) - c(2, 5)",
    "fghij, Number of dogs barking? (text) - 2",
    "c(qwerty, thnmjy), c(Number of cows in the field?, How many sheep have lambs?) c(text, text) - c(0, 7)",
    "poiuy, Number of birds flying? (text) - 0",
    "lkjhg, How many frogs in the pond? (text) - 3",
    "mnbvc, How many fish swimming? (text) - 4"
  ),
  category = rep("a", 6),
  index = rep("b", 6))
```

Code that has been used

```
output <- df_1 |>
  separate(key, into = c("key", "title_type"), sep = ",") |>
  separate(title_type, into = c("title", "type"), sep = " \\(") |>
  separate(type, into = c("type", "answer"), sep = "\\) - ") |>
  mutate(title = str_replace_all(title, " ", "_"))

print(output)
```

The desired output

[image: desired output table]

###############################

Updated JSON file with the amendment of "answer" to include values that are formatted as logic, character and lists.

```
json <- '{
    "name": "circle",
    "ID": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "questions": [
        {
            "local": "Q1",
            "fields": [
                {"key": ["abcde", "abcd"], "title": ["How many cats are meowing?", "How many cats are sleeping?"], "type": ["text", "text"], "answer": ["2", "5"]},
                {"key": "fghij", "title": "Number of dogs barking?", "type": "text", "answer": "2"},
                {"key": ["qwerty", "thnmjy"], "title": ["Number of cows in the field?", "How many sheep have lambs?"], "type": ["text", "text"], "answer": ["0", "7"]},
                {"key": "poiuy", "title": "Number of birds flying?", "type": "text", "answer": "0"},
                {"key": "lkjhg", "title": "How many frogs in the pond?", "type": "text", "answer": [
                                {"Could be one", “Might be two”, “hard to say”}]},
                {"key": "mnbvc", "title": "How many fish swimming?", "type": "text", "answer": ["True", “False”]}
            ],
            "category": "a",
            "index": "b"
       },
        {
            "local": "Q1",
            "fields": [
                {"key": ["abcde", "abcd"], "title": ["How many cats are meowing?", "How many cats are sleeping?"], "type": ["text", "text"], "answer": ["2", "5"]},
                {"key": "fghij", "title": "Number of dogs barking?", "type": "text", "answer": "2"},
                {"key": ["qwerty", "thnmjy"], "title": ["Number of cows in the field?", "How many sheep have lambs?"], "type": ["text", "text"], "answer": ["0", "7"]},
                {"key": "poiuy", "title": "Number of birds flying?", "type": "text", "answer": "0"},
                {"key": "lkjhg", "title": "How many frogs in the pond?", "type": "text", "answer": [
                                {"There is no answer"}]},
                {"key": "mnbvc", "title": "How many fish swimming?", "type": "text", "answer": ["True", “False”]}
            ],
            "category": "a",
            "index": "b"
       },
        {
            "local": "Q1",
            "fields": [
                {"key": ["abcde", "abcd"], "title": ["How many cats are meowing?", "How many cats are sleeping?"], "type": ["text", "text"], "answer": ["2", "5"]},
                {"key": "fghij", "title": "Number of dogs barking?", "type": "text", "answer": "2"},
                {"key": ["qwerty", "thnmjy"], "title": ["Number of cows in the field?", "How many sheep have lambs?"], "type": ["text", "text"], "answer": ["0", "7"]},
                {"key": "poiuy", "title": "Number of birds flying?", "type": "text", "answer": "0"},
                {"key": "lkjhg", "title": "How many frogs in the pond?", "type": "text", "answer": [
                           {"The answer is one"}]},
                {"key": "mnbvc", "title": "How many fish swimming?", "type": "text", "answer": ["True", “False”]}
            ],
            "category": "a",
            "index": "b"
       }
    ]
}'
```

Comment: Are these list columns? If so, use `tidyr::unnest_wider()`. If not or you need more help, please add some of your actual data to your question using `dput(head(df_1))`.

Comment: Thanks, yes there are list columns.  I will try the tidyr::unnest_wider() suggestion. Unfortunately, I am unable to share the actual data.

Comment: You can still use `dput()` to share sample data that isn't your actual data. Or you can use `dput()` to produce your actual data and then modify the values it so it becomes sample data. The 2 rows like you show would be plenty, so this shouldn't be too hard. The key is that we get the data structure and all the classes correct, which `dput()` will do automatically.

Comment: db2020, see if `df_1 <- structure(list(col_A = structure(list(list(c("abcdef", "ghijkl"), c("How many cats (approximately) started meowing?", "How many dogs (approximately) have barked at the cats?"), c("text", "text"), c("123", "456"))), class = "AsIs"), col_F = "other_1", col_G = "other_2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))` meets your sample-data expectations; if so, please [edit] your question and add it there (pls don't leave it here in a comment). (*Edited*)

Comment: Thank you r2evans. I have added a different example dummy dataset that represents more closely my data.

Comment: I think `separate_wider_regex` would be a good match here, see updated answer below.

Comment: Thank you John, I have updated the dataset, as I realise that my previous dummy df did not fully reflect the nested data within the actual dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Second complete rewrite, now using the original json.

Well ... an *updated* json, modified for <strike>two</strike> *three* things that I think are artifacts of deriving a sample for the question. Namely:

- it is missing a quote, a comma, a right-bracket, and has smart-quotes, none of which are valid json;
- I'm inferring since `ID` has three values, there should be paired `$questions`, so the questions should really be a list of three frames. For this, I'll just copy the original `questions` into a list of 3;
- some lists erroneously had dict-like braces around them.

Updated json, now including the `"answer"` fields:

```r
json <- '{
    "name": "circle",
    "ID": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "questions": [
        {
            "local": "Q1",
            "fields": [
                {"key": ["abcde", "abcd"], "title": ["How many cats are meowing?", "How many cats are sleeping?"], "type": ["text", "text"], "answer": ["2", "5"]},
                {"key": "fghij", "title": "Number of dogs barking?", "type": "text", "answer": "2"},
                {"key": ["qwerty", "thnmjy"], "title": ["Number of cows in the field?", "How many sheep have lambs?"], "type": ["text", "text"], "answer": ["0", "7"]},
                {"key": "poiuy", "title": "Number of birds flying?", "type": "text", "answer": "0"},
                {"key": "lkjhg", "title": "How many frogs in the pond?", "type": "text", "answer": [
                                "Could be one", "Might be two", "hard to say"]},
                {"key": "mnbvc", "title": "How many fish swimming?", "type": "text", "answer": ["True", "False"]}
            ],
            "category": "a",
            "index": "b"
       },
        {
            "local": "Q1",
            "fields": [
                {"key": ["abcde", "abcd"], "title": ["How many cats are meowing?", "How many cats are sleeping?"], "type": ["text", "text"], "answer": ["2", "5"]},
                {"key": "fghij", "title": "Number of dogs barking?", "type": "text", "answer": "2"},
                {"key": ["qwerty", "thnmjy"], "title": ["Number of cows in the field?", "How many sheep have lambs?"], "type": ["text", "text"], "answer": ["0", "7"]},
                {"key": "poiuy", "title": "Number of birds flying?", "type": "text", "answer": "0"},
                {"key": "lkjhg", "title": "How many frogs in the pond?", "type": "text", "answer": [
                                "There is no answer"]},
                {"key": "mnbvc", "title": "How many fish swimming?", "type": "text", "answer": ["True", "False"]}
            ],
            "category": "a",
            "index": "b"
       },
        {
            "local": "Q1",
            "fields": [
                {"key": ["abcde", "abcd"], "title": ["How many cats are meowing?", "How many cats are sleeping?"], "type": ["text", "text"], "answer": ["2", "5"]},
                {"key": "fghij", "title": "Number of dogs barking?", "type": "text", "answer": "2"},
                {"key": ["qwerty", "thnmjy"], "title": ["Number of cows in the field?", "How many sheep have lambs?"], "type": ["text", "text"], "answer": ["0", "7"]},
                {"key": "poiuy", "title": "Number of birds flying?", "type": "text", "answer": "0"},
                {"key": "lkjhg", "title": "How many frogs in the pond?", "type": "text", "answer": [
                           "The answer is one"]},
                {"key": "mnbvc", "title": "How many fish swimming?", "type": "text", "answer": ["True", "False"]}
            ],
            "category": "a",
            "index": "b"
       }
    ]
}'
```

Assuming that is correct, then this is actually quite simple using `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```r
L <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json)
L$questions |>
  mutate(fields = lapply(fields, \(z) unnest(z, cols = names(z)))) |>
  bind_cols(as.data.frame(L[!names(L) == "questions"])) |>
  unnest(fields)
# # A tibble: 29 × 9
#    local key    title                        type  answer       category index name   ID   
#    <chr> <chr>  <chr>                        <chr> <chr>        <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#  1 Q1    abcde  How many cats are meowing?   text  2            a        b     circle 1    
#  2 Q1    abcd   How many cats are sleeping?  text  5            a        b     circle 1    
#  3 Q1    fghij  Number of dogs barking?      text  2            a        b     circle 1    
#  4 Q1    qwerty Number of cows in the field? text  0            a        b     circle 1    
#  5 Q1    thnmjy How many sheep have lambs?   text  7            a        b     circle 1    
#  6 Q1    poiuy  Number of birds flying?      text  0            a        b     circle 1    
#  7 Q1    lkjhg  How many frogs in the pond?  text  Could be one a        b     circle 1    
#  8 Q1    lkjhg  How many frogs in the pond?  text  Might be two a        b     circle 1    
#  9 Q1    lkjhg  How many frogs in the pond?  text  hard to say  a        b     circle 1    
# 10 Q1    mnbvc  How many fish swimming?      text  True         a        b     circle 1    
# # ℹ 19 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Thank you r2evans.  Tried both baseR and dplyr.  the former errored to Error in rep(1:nrow(df_1), times = sapply(tmp1, nrow)) : 
  invalid 'times' argument.... the latter errored to Caused by error in `do.call()`:
! second argument must be a list.... I will check my dataset again tomorrow.

Comment: The dplyr approach now works on dummy data.  I adapted that code as follows (this works on dummy dataset more closely based on my actual data)...  output <- df_1 |>
  separate(key, into = c("key", "title_type"), sep = ",") |>
  separate(title_type, into = c("title", "type"), sep = " \\(") |>
  separate(type, into = c("type", "answer"), sep = "\\) - ") |>
  mutate(title = str_replace_all(title, " ", "_"))... I am attempting to make it work on the actual dataset...

Comment: I've (completely) updated the answer based on your updated `df_1`, see if it changes your luck.

Comment: Thank you r2evans.  I have revised the dummy dataset above, as I realise now that I did not fully represent my actual data in the dummy dataset I previously presented.  The actual data does have multiply levels of nested data in json format which I have expanded down to the last nest (which is what I am attempting to expand)  and then save in csv format for further analysis.

Comment: You have updated to two distinct datasets: one that should be raw json, and one that's a frame, though their sample data are different. Since you say you're getting json initially, I suspect it'll be better to go from that instead of the frame, since the frame looks like some flattening-gone-amiss. Assuming the json sample, what is the expected output? Either convert the json to the same fields and content as the frame, or provide an expected output given the json data. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you r2evans for the advice.  I have updated the json data structure with the same fields as the dataframe and have added a table of the desired output.  I want to fully expand all the columns and rows.  I have a more complex and larger json file I would want to apply any successful code from this example to.

Comment: See my edit @db2020, I think I'm finally onto something here :-)

Comment: Thank you r2evans.  I attempted most recent code without success.  Closer inspection of data showed that the answer column has mixed formats with rows containing lists (formatted as 'list of 2' (chr)) and other rows with single values (logic and chr formats).

Comment: I have tried to drop the answer col to check the code, without success... 
L <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json)
col_remove_answer <- function(fields) {
  fields$answer <- NULL
  return(fields)
}
L$questions <- lapply(L$questions, function(question) {
  question$fields <- lapply(question$fields, col_remove_answer)
  return(question)
})
result <- L$questions %>% unnest(fields) %>% bind_cols(as.data.frame(L[!names(L) == "questions"]))

Comment: Your sample data has no "answer" field.

Comment: Hi r2evans.  I have updated the JSON file in the question.  The "answer" component has logic, character and list elements.

Comment: The json you pasted is not valid json. Try running `jsonlite::fromJSON(json)` to see what is broken.

Comment: When I fix that (removing spurious `{`/`}` where they are not really dicts), the code in my answer works unchanged and includes the `"answer"` field.

Comment: Thank you for the amendments.  After fetching the source data it is flattened as a data.frame ahead of using your code.  I would imagine this is what is affecting the implementation of the code on the actual data.

Comment: I don't know how you are getting the data. If you're calling `jsonlite::fromJSON` yourself, then you can add `simplifyDataFrame=FALSE`; if you're using `httr::GET` or `httr2::` or `rvest::`, then you should be able to do something similar, or ask for the content `as="text"`.

Comment: Thank you r2evans.  I will explore the suggested fixes and update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite for new, non-nested data. `separate_wider_regex` lets us specify what we expect to see in each field. In this case I've just specified the two delimiters of `", "` and `" - "` and assigned the rest to `txt1`, `txt2`, and `txt3`.

```
df_1 |>
  separate_wider_regex(key, c(txt1 = ".*", ", ", txt2 = ".*", " - ", txt3 = ".*"), 
                       cols_remove = FALSE) # skip if orig not needed

  A tibble: 6 × 7
  name   area     ID txt1   txt2                                txt3  key                                            
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>                               <chr> <chr>                                          
1 circle local     1 abcde  Number of cats meowing? (text)      2     abcde, Number of cats meowing? (text) - 2      
2 circle local     2 fghij  Number of dogs barking? (text)      2     fghij, Number of dogs barking? (text) - 2      
3 circle local     3 qwerty Number of cows in the field? (text) 0     qwerty, Number of cows in the field? (text) - 0
4 circle local     1 poiuy  Number of birds flying? (text)      0     poiuy, Number of birds flying? (text) - 0      
5 circle local     2 lkjhg  How many frogs in the pond? (text)  3     lkjhg, How many frogs in the pond? (text) - 3  
6 circle local     3 mnbvc  How many fish swimming? (text)      4     mnbvc, How many fish swimming? (text) - 4
```

Using sample data:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  name = "circle",
  area = "local",
  ID = c(1, 2, 3),
  key = c(
    "abcde, Number of cats meowing? (text) - 2",
    "fghij, Number of dogs barking? (text) - 2",
    "qwerty, Number of cows in the field? (text) - 0",
    "poiuy, Number of birds flying? (text) - 0",
    "lkjhg, How many frogs in the pond? (text) - 3",
    "mnbvc, How many fish swimming? (text) - 4"
  )
)
```

---

Old answer, appropriate for original nested structure:

```
library(tidyverse) # dplyr + tidyr used here
df_1 |>
  unnest_wider(col_A) |>
  rename(col_A = 1, col_B = 2, col_C = 3, col_D = 4) |>
  unnest_longer(col_A:col_D)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 2 × 6
  col_A  col_B                                                  col_C col_D col_F   col_G  
  <chr>  <chr>                                                  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
1 abcdef How many cats (approximately) started meowing?         text  123   other_1 other_2
2 ghijkl How many dogs (approximately) have barked at the cats? text  456   other_1 other_2
```

using sample data:

```
df_1 <- structure(list(col_A = structure(list(list(c("abcdef", "ghijkl"), 
                  c("How many cats (approximately) started meowing?", 
                    "How many dogs (approximately) have barked at the cats?"), 
                  c("text", "text"), c("123", "456"))), class = "AsIs"), 
                  col_F = "other_1", col_G = "other_2"), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```